# How to implement a favorite icon on separate pictures of a carousel using Ruby on Rails (v.7)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carousel, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7, favorites

[image: 1]

I have a photo sharing app built on rails that allows users to like, comment and favorite each other's pictures.

If a user uploads multiple pictures/videos at once, these are shown in a carousel (using bootstrap 5.2). I'm trying to add a favorite icon to each separate post within a  carousel.

For now, if a user favorites a carousel, it  will save all pictures/videos that are part of it, whereas I want to allow users to only save the unique picture or video they would like to have.

Any direction on how to implement this is really appreciated!

These are some snippets of my code:

**My Routes**

```
  resources :events do
    resources :attachments, only: [:new, :create, :index, :destroy]
  end

  resources :attachments, except: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :edit, :update]
    resources :likes, only: :create
    resources :favorites, only: :create
  end
  resources :comments, only: [:destroy]
  resources :likes, only: :destroy
  resources :favorites, only: :destroy
end
```

**Attachment model**

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
has_many_attached :posts
has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy

validates :posts, presence: true
end
```

**Favorite model**

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :attachment
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :attachment_id}
end
```

**Attachment show page**

```
<div class="attachment-post">
              <% if @attachment.posts.attached? %>
                <% if @attachment.posts.length > 1 %>
                  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                      <% @attachment.posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
                      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="<%="#{index}" %>" class="<%= index.zero? ? "active" : nil %>", aria-current="<%= index.zero? ? "true" : nil %>" aria-label="Slide <%="#{index}" %>"></button>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <% @attachment.posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
                        <div class="carousel-item <%= index.zero? ? "active" : nil %>">
                          <% if post.content_type.include?("image") %>
                            <%= cl_image_tag post.key, class:"img-event-gallery d-block w-100", crop: :fill %>
                          <% else %>
                            <%= cl_video_tag post.key, controls: true, class:"img-event-gallery d-block w-100", crop: :fill %>
                          <% end %>
                        </div>
                        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                        </button>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <% else %>
                  <% if @attachment.posts[0].content_type.include?("image") %>
                    <%= cl_image_tag @attachment.posts[0].key, class:"img-event-gallery", crop: :fill %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%= cl_video_tag @attachment.posts[0].key, controls: true, class:"img-event-gallery", crop: :fill%>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              <% else %>
                <h3>Upload your images by clicking on the plus sign</h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>

            <div class="post-content">
              <div class="like-and-delete-and-favorite d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class = "likes-icon d-flex justify-content-start" >
                  <div class="likes-icon-number">
                    <p class="likes"><%= pluralize(@attachment.likes.count, "Like") %>
                      <% like = current_user.likes.find_by(attachment: @attachment) %>
                    <% if current_user %>
                      <% if like.nil? %>
                        <%= link_to  attachment_likes_path(@attachment), data: {turbo_method: :post}, class:"likes-icons" do %>
                          <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        <% end %>
                      <% else %>

                        <%= link_to like_path(like), data: {turbo_method: :delete}, class:"likes-icons" do %>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
                        <% end %>
                      <% end %>
                    <% else %>
                      <%# signup %>
                        <%= link_to attachment_likes_path(@attachment), data: {turbo_method: :post},
                          class:"likes-icons" do %>
                          <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="favorite-icon">
                  <% favorite = current_user.favorites.find_by(attachment: @attachment) %>
                  <% if current_user %>
                    <% if favorite.nil? %>
                      <%= link_to  attachment_favorites_path(@attachment), data: {turbo_method: :post}, class:"favorites-icons" do %>
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-bookmark"></i>
                      <% end %>
                    <% else %>

                      <%= link_to favorite_path(favorite), data: {turbo_method: :delete}, class:"favorites-icons" do %>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>
                      <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%# signup %>
                      <%= link_to attachment_favorites_path(@attachment), data: {turbo_method: :post},
                        class:"favorites-icons" do %>
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-bookmark"></i>
                      <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

when the picture is not added to favorites :

```
<a data-turbo-method="post" class="favorites-icons" href="/attachments/7/favorites"> 
  <i class="fa-regular fa-bookmark"></i> 
</a>
```

vs when it is added to favorites:

```
<a data-turbo-method="delete" class="favorites-icons" href="/favorites/59"> 
  <i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i> 
</a>
```

Comment: Are you putting the link to LIKE only in the `active` photo of the carousel? What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. At the moment the favorite icon sits next to the like icon. Both are for attachments and not the posts themselves within a carousel. I'm adding a screenshot in the initial question to clarify. Both appear under the attachment in the html file. I believe the favorite icon should be within the active part of the carousel but I'm not too sure how to implement this.

Comment: I would look at the actual generated HTML in the browser. Compare the code of the favorite buttons for the active picture to one of the non-active pictures. Maybe post those two code snippets.

Comment: when the picture is not added to favorites : 
<a data-turbo-method="post" class="favorites-icons" href="/attachments/7/favorites">
<i class="fa-regular fa-bookmark"></i>
</a>

vs when it is added to favorites: 

<a data-turbo-method="delete" class="favorites-icons" href="/favorites/59">
<i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>
</a>

Comment: So is that adding a favorite for all photos in `/attachments/7`? I thought I understood how your models are working and how things are related but I see `@attachment.posts`. What is the Post model and how does it all relate? Can you give us a more clear mapping of how Attachments, Posts, Favorites all relate?

Comment: Correct. If I favourite attachment with id 7 it will favorite the whole set of pictures and videos included in this attachment which are displayed in a carousel format. Posts are not a model on their own, it is simply added to distinguish if there is  only one video/photo uploaded (and thus display it normally) or more than one picture added by the user (we would then display it as a carousel instead of a top to bottom view). Hope this is clearer?

Comment: I think you just need to rework the link to favorite so it resembles the link to un-favorite. i.e. it should target the image directly. i.e. have a POST to create a new favorite for that ID. It should look just like your delete link: `/favorites/59`. If the item you are trying to favorite is not stored yet as an individual image then you will need to do some sort of ".build" in the `new` action that creates the carousel. Can't really help with that since I can't see any of your controller code.